# Should use Firestore + HiveDB or only Firestore with offline support

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, hivedb

I'm a newbie in mobile development with Flutter.
My application requires real-time updates from the server to devices, however, the data must be changed a few times per day then I want to apply local caching for it.
I’m considering 2 options.
First, using Firebase Firestore with a real-time update then anytime the server updates data, saving on Firestore devices will get updated and stored in HiveDB. It means Firestone looks like servers send events. I think this one has less latency, is fast, and saves cost.
The second option will use only Firestore with offline compatibility mode, but i don't know so many details about this option.

For any update I will call APIs to the server not allowing to write data to firestore directly (CQRS pattern).

Any suggestions for me for this case. Thank you a lots.

Which one should i go? Or any alternative options?

Comment: Firestore has a cache first if you want to try it out, but If you don't feel convinced you can always use a local DB

Answer (score 1):

**Firestore + HiveDB**
Advantages: Real-time updates, offline support, fast access.
Considerations: Data consistency, complexity.
**Firestore with offline compatibility mode**
Advantages: Real-time updates, offline support, simplified implementation.
Considerations: Limited offline capabilities, network dependencies.
Choose ultimately based on your needs and factors like data consistency, complexity, offline functionality, and network dependencies.

Comment: just give an update that I have used both  Firestore + HiveDB and Firestore with offline compatibility mode for different areas to optimize the costs and speed.